# Sort array of hashes having duplicate values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following array of hashes:

```
arr = [{:id=>1, :val=>30}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1002, :val=>82}]
```

I need to:

- sort it by the value for `:val`, and
- if several hashes have the same value, their relative positions should either reflect the original order or the reversed order depending on whether the sort by `:val` value is ascending or descending

like this:

```
arr.sort_by_ascending_order.map{|x| x[:id]}
# => [1, 2, 1002] 
arr.sort_by_descending_order.map{|x| x[:id]}
# => [1002, 2, 1]
```

I cannot guarantee the second condition. For example,

```
arr.sort{|x,y| x[:val] <=> y[:val]}.map{|x| x[:id]}
# => [1, 2, 1002] 
arr.sort{|x,y| y[:val] <=> x[:val]}.map{|x| x[:id]}
# => [1002, 1, 2]
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Comment: Please clarify the desired sort criterion. @Stefan's answer suggests you want to sort on `:val` with ties broken by `:id`.Is that correct?

Comment: @CarySwoveland You are right. This question was horribly worded. I hope I made it clear. And the question had nothing to do with Ruby versions. The older one in MRI happened to have what the OP wanted by coincidence, but that part is not specified in Ruby (Ruby sort is unstable sort).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide an array:

```
arr = [{:id=>1, :val=>30}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1002, :val=>82}]

arr.sort { |x, y| [x[:val], x[:id]] <=> [y[:val], y[:id]] }
#=> [{:id=>1, :val=>30}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1002, :val=>82}]

arr.sort { |x, y| [y[:val], y[:id]] <=> [x[:val], x[:id]] }
#=> [{:id=>1002, :val=>82}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1, :val=>30}]
```

This will sort by `:val` first and then by `:id` (see [`Array#<=>`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E) for details).

You could also use [`sort_by`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by):

```
arr.sort_by { |h| [h[:val], h[:id]] }
#=> [{:id=>1, :val=>30}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1002, :val=>82}]
```

**Update:**

Of course, this is not limited to hash values. You could use the element's index (as [suggested by sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28633534/sort-array-of-hashes-having-duplicate-values/28633659#comment45568194_28633659)) as a secondary sort condition to achieve a [stable sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability):

```
arr.sort_by.with_index { |h, i| [h[:val], i] }
#=> [{:id=>1, :val=>30}, {:id=>2, :val=>30}, {:id=>1002, :val=>82}]
```

Comment: It's easy and good solution, thanks, I'll use it, but I'm just wondering is it a bug in 1.9.3?

Comment: @SergeiStruk No, it is your mind's bug. Behavior for the order among a tie is not specified. Both Ruby versions are correct. It is your bug to assume otherwise. Don't try to attribute your mistake to other people. Don't use the word bug on other people/software easily.

Comment: @Stefan Even though the OP accepted this, I don't think this is what OP asked for. Even though the condition "if several hashes have same values, their positions will be changed after changing of sorting direction" is horribly worded, it is clear that OP makes no mention to the value for `:id`. It looks like the OP wanted to reflect the original position. That would be done by `with_index`. Probably the OP accepted this without even looking at the code.

Comment: @Stefan Code is incorrect, I don't argue regarding this, but I'm not sure that behavior of 1.9.3 is correct. What do you think about this?: https://gist.github.com/SergeiStruk/4d9c1579e078e902e5e4

Comment: @SergeiStruk Ruby (MRI) uses quicksort, which is not stable. I've updated my answer with another example.

Comment: @SergeiStruk you have to change the input to get different results:  `%w(a b xx).sort_by(&:length)` returns `["a", "b", "xx"]` (a before b) whereas `%w(xx a b).sort_by(&:length)` returns `["b", "a", "xx"]` (b before a).